# flutter provider of a value in the next page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Suppose that we have a flutter project with two screens, the first one is a dashboard or landing page that reads a value (say count number) from the second which is next to it.

I tried the provider as a state manager but the problem is the landing page reads a null value because the second one has to be loaded first to set the counter and that doesn't happen.

Question is how can i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: When creating the provider, did you initialize the value or class at 0?

Comment: that's a solution for the null value but it will read it always as zero regardless of the actual value.

Comment: you should create that provider before the MaterialApp ang get the actual value so it initializes before the landing page (not initialize it at the second page), maybe a minimal example code can help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`ChangeNotifierProvider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html) wrapping your first screen, usually this is done on the `MaterialApp` configuration. There you also initialize your values to their default.

Then on the second page you can get you `ChangeNotifier` and chenge it's value so the first page will get it updated.

Take a look at the `ChangeNotifierProvider` docs and examples on how to setup `Provider` and use it as a State Management solution. Some examples [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple), [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6373413-state-management-with-provider) and a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I).